# Task.Run - антипаттерн async/await? C#

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Недавно прочитал [статью на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/dodopizzaio/blog/435666/) (**upd:** из комментов понял, что нужно прицепить цитату, по которой далее вопрос)

> Как только код доходит до метода Task.Run(), достаётся другой поток из пула потоков и в нём исполняется код, который мы передали в Task.Run(). Старый поток, как и положено приличному потоку, возвращается в пул и ждёт, когда его снова позовут делать работу. Новый поток выполняет переданный код, доходит до синхронной операции, синхронно выполняет её (ждёт пока операция не будет выполнена) и идёт дальше по коду. Иными словами, операция так и осталась синхронной: мы, как и раньше, используем поток во время выполнения синхронной операции. Единственное отличие — мы потратили время на переключение контекста при вызове Task.Run() и при возврате в ExecuteOperation(). Всё стало немножечко хуже.

Один из вопросов, который там рассматривается: вызов `Task.Run` - это антипаттерн, и нужен он только для отзывчивости GUI.

Вопрос именно про `Task.Run(() => _anyWork())`, где `_anyWork()` содержит синхронный код. То, что написано в статье, звучит достаточно логично, если делать так:

```
await DoWork();
...

Task DoWork() => Task.Run(_work);
```

Да, в таком случае создается лишняя нагрузка на пул потоков. Но, ведь если делать так:

```
var task1 = DoWork1();
var task2 = DoWork2();
var task3 = DoWork3();
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

`Task.Run` сразу превращается в нормальный код, ведь так?

Поток, который будет выполнять этот код, создаст три других потока (**upd**: оговорился: инициирует добавление работы в очередь, которая будет запущена в `ThreadPool`), которые параллельно будут выполнять свою работу параллельно. Дальше, когда он встретит `await` - он вернет управление (в итоге, скорее всего, вернется в пул). Исправьте, пожалуйста, если не так.

Если это так - возникает вопрос: где проходит эта грань, между плохой реализацией, и нормальной? В небиблиотечном коде понятно - если вызывается метод, а ожидание где-то дальше - то можно делать `Task.Run`. В библиотечном же - с одной стороны, мы можем распараллелить работу своих методов, если клиент будет ожидать их после вызова. С другой - мы можем зря увеличить нагрузку, если клиент будет ожидать результат сразу при вызове. Знать точно, как будет вызывать методы клиент - мы не можем, можем только дать рекомендации в документации.

Возможно есть какие-то официальные рекомендации MS? На msdn я нашел только сухое описание работы методов.

Comment: Вы можете сконденсировать мысль, выраженную в статье до MVCE? Чтобы не требовалось ее читать для понимания Вашего вопроса

Comment: _Поток, который будет выполнять этот код, создаст три других потока_ - вообще говоря, это не так

Comment: 1) это `Task.Run` не создает новый поток, а берет готовый поток из пула

Comment: 2) `Task.Run сразу превращается в нормальный код, ведь так?` что значит нормальный код? Критении нормальности кода?

Comment: 3) `создается лишняя нагрузка на пул потоков` пул потоков существует для того, чтоюы его нагружали. Что значит лишняя нагрузка?

Comment: 4) `Возможно есть какие-то официальные рекомендации MS` рекомендации по поводу чего?

Comment: 3 - лишняя нагрузка, т.к по сути, если исполнять в Task.Run синхронный код, при этом await-ить его сразу - будет просто из пула поднят поток, лишнее переключение контекста, а текущий поток уйдет в пул. Сейчас цитату из статьи добавлю.

Comment: 5) `где проходит эта грань, между плохой реализацией, и нормальной?` - плохая - это та, что не работает. Нормальная - та, что работает. Это можно сказать наверняка. Остальное - уже зависит от деталей задачи и реализации

Comment: 3- если синхронный код без `Task.Run` запускать в UI потоке  WPF приложения, то UI весь встанет, пока код не исполнится. В таком случае, я предпочту `Task.Run`

Comment: Получается автор написал неэффективный код, с предположением, что этот код запскается уже из пула потоков, и при этом он изспользовал `Task.Run` и  вы делаете какие то выводы по поводу приментмости `Task.Run` только на этом примере? Давайте и C# запретим м пул потоков, они тоже в том примере есть и такую же роль играют, что `Task.Run`

Comment: ответ же простой - если у вас есть синхронная операция, но вы не хотите блокировать текущий поток - то `Task.Run` - ваш выбор. Если занятость текущего потока вас не волнует - выполняйте синхронно в нем

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Один из вопросов, который там рассматривается: вызов Task.Run - это антипаттерн, и нужен он только для отзывчивости GUI.

[Task.Run Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Ставит в очередь заданную работу для запуска в ThreadPool и возвращает задачу или дескриптор Task для этой работы.

То есть Task.Run - это способ выполнить какую-то работу в пуле потоков с возможностью ожидания результата асинхронно.

Когда это может понадобится? Возможные примеры использования:

1) Запуск IO/CPU нагрузки пуле потоков, чтобы не грузить основной UI поток ([пример](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.SteamModule/Models/SteamServiceViewModel.cs#L108))

2) Запуск асинхронного кода синхронно из UI потока. Такое может потребоваться, когда у вас большое приложение и вы постепенно переходите на асинхронные вызовы вместо синхронных, но не везде пока можете вызывать ваш новый API асинхронно, пр этом вам надо избегать дедлоков в UI потоке, например `Task.Run(()=>CallSmthgAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` - это не оч красивый код и он должен быть исправлен, но не всегода можно внедрить асинхронные вызовы за один заход, потому я такое сам делал и видел иногда.

Когда это НЕ надо: когда вас не заботит факт блокировки текущего потока какой то синхронной работой.

В прмере в вопросе задача и так уже запущена в пуле потоков, потому переключаться в другой поток и там выполнять что то синхронное смысла не имеет. Но если бы та же работа была запущена из UI потока, то без `Task.Run` все UI приложение бы встало колом.

Что касается библиотечного кода. Стройте ваш API и его реализацию исходя из требований и вариантов использования.  Если у вас много I/O операций (работа с файлами, с сетью, с БД), то это по сути самой собой намекает на необходимость асинхронного API. Если вас смущает выбор между синхронным API и асинхронным, то реализуйте оба, пусть клиент выбирает,что ему нужно.

Отсюда вывод: самое главное, чтобы не наломать дров, всегда знайте что вы делаете и зачем вы это делаете. Переключайте контекст тогда, когда у вас есть причина это делать. Если каждая строка вашего кода будет обоснована и иметь причину, почему она именно так написана, то проблем с выбором хороший код/ плохой код у вас будет гораздо меньше.

Comment: А если я GUI не хочу подвешивать, стоит ли делать так - `await Task.Run(async () => await PartialAsyncMethod());` ? Визуально получается подозрительно, но формально вроде всё правильно.

Comment: @Monk чем это будет отличаться от простого `await PartialAsyncMethod()`? С точки зрения фризов UI потока

Comment: В моем случае вся обработка сразу уйдет из UI потока, в вашем - уйдет только когда закончится синхронный код. Или нет? Я почему и спрашиваю.

Comment: @Monk да, но, учитывая, что мы все ресурсоемкие опрации и так выполяем асинхронно, то остаются простые и быстрые операции для синхронного выполнения. В моем случае да, они выполнятся в UI потоке, в вашем сначала произойдет переключение контекста, потом выполнение их в фоновом потоке. Что тут быстрее - большой вопрос, переключение контекста - это медленная оперия. Нагружают ли простые и быстрые операции UI поток? Нверное да, но я не думаю, что юзер это как то заметит.

Comment: @Monk Кстати, имейте ввиду, что сйечас мы обсуждаем ваш код, как будто он был запущен из UI потока. Запуск его из фонового потока, конечно, смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

Код метода *Async выполняется в **текущем потоке до первого await**. И текущий поток будет захвачен. Например, HttpClient до начала асинхронного запроса синхронно запрашивает dns, что может быть долгой операцией.

И вы можете решить, что вас больше беспокоит - ожидание текущего потока или накладные расходы от Task.Run() (которые минимальны по факту, разве что раздувают код)

Answer (score 0):

использовать `Task`:

- если внутри нужно использовать асинхронную операцию:

  - внутри их несколько
  - синхронный код и асинхронная операция
  - [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c/19103343#19103343) интересная статья о `using(IDisposable)` и потенциальном баге
- если ты делаешь свою собственную асинхронную операцию (например превращаешь событие в `Task`) - часто используют `TaskCompletionSource`

второе похоже на `I/O-bound` операцию - не уверен, писать ли отдельным пунктом

Comment: возможно, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896856/is-async-await-suitable-for-methods-that-are-both-io-and-cpu-bound) будет полезная информация

Comment: Так называемый "потенциальный баг" по ссылке - есть просто баг, который можно создать по невнимательности или если совсем не понимать, что ты делаешь. То есть, тот пример не является чем-то удивительным и требующим на себя обратить внимание. Вряд ли стоит удивляться, если ты создашь Task с помощью объекта, который после его создания сразу же освобождает ресурсы и возвращает Task, который будет отрабатывать, вероятно, с полями объекта, ресурсы которого были освобождены.

Comment: ага! забыл что оно работает как `finaly` - забыл переписать код - и выйдет баг "из ничего"!