# В чем разница между Task.Run и async/await

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

В чем разница если по сути можно отправить в **Task.Run(SomeMethod)** метод и не писать

```
async void AsyncMethod()
{
   
   await Task.Run(SomeMethod);

}

public void SomeMethod(){}
```

Comment: Хотите понять, что происходит? Это не так просто объяснить. Можете начать [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1105232/179763), потом [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947565/179763), и [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/781007/179763), ну и по классике, [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416086/179763).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.Run()` запускает код в потоке, то есть это почти то же самое, что создание и запуск потока `Thread.Start()` с одной разницей, `Task.Run()` по умолчанию берет поток из пула, а  `Thread.Start()` создает новый поток.

`async` и `await` это система ожидания асинхронных задач, и к многопоточному программированию имеет не прямое отношение.

`Task.Run()` или `Thread.Start()` стоит использовать при длительной нагрузке на процессор, например в сложных вычислениях (CPU-bound задач), чтобы распределить нагрузку на несколько ядер процессора. `async` и `await` следует использовать для обычного запроса на сервер, работы с файлами, базами данных и других операций ввода-вывода (IO-bound задач).

Подробнее можно почитать в документации: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: а в какое преимущества у async/await?

Comment: @n_enrai49, в производительности, так как создание потока требует выделение памяти и работу сборщика мусора. А в одном async методе может быть несколько await, что гораздо выгоднее.

Comment: то есть множество задач лучше запускать через async/await, а не через пропись Task.Run() нескольких раз?

Comment: @n_enrai49, да.

Comment: Множество коротких по времени выполнения - да. множество тяжелых(несколько тысяч и более) - на своей реализации очереди потоков, много потоков - плохо. Тяжелые задачи в async await - плохо.

Comment: немножечко поправлю текст. 1) Таск представляет собой операцию, а не поток. 2) Task.Run() обычно шлет задачу в пул потоков, Thread.Start() создает новый поток. Луше использовать пул потоков. 3) async await не снижают никакую производительность, это вообще не про производительность 4) `множество задач лучше запускать через async/await` - async/await не запускает задачи вообще, это способ дождаться выполнения операции 5) Совсем не покрыта тема асинхронных операций, по сути причину, зачем async/await вообще добавили

Comment: `Task является реализацией потока` не является, это ошибочное суждение.

Comment: Удивлён, как ещё минусов не понаставили. Особенно за бред про замедление в 10 раз от использования асинхронности. Нет, можно, наверное, придумать пример, в котором так будет, но это будет очень искусственный пример, не из реальной жизни.

Comment: @CrazyElf я надеюсь, автор займется улучшением ответа на основе комментариев и поглубже изучит матчасть. Минусить принятый ответ - последнее дело.

Comment: @aepot Будем надеяться, да. Так то я лично минусю только за явное неуважение к сообществу, а за неверный ответ просто не ставлю плюс. Но я видел тут, что за некорректные ответы могут и заминусить.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну, строго говоря, асинхронность добавляет переключение контекста, потому одна выбранная задача асинхронно может отработать медленней, чем синхронно. Для одной задачи так часто и бывает. Но просто асинхронность никогда и не предназначалась для ускорения одной задачи. Асинхронность вообще не про ускорение.

Comment: @tym32167 Так и многопоточность добавляет переключение контекста, теоретически тоже можно придумать случаи (и они реально бывают), когда многопоточность замедляет работу. Но сходу говорить про 10-кратное снижение производительности из-за async/await - это как-то как-то )

Comment: @CrazyElf так далеко ходить не надо, я в одном из дубликатов даже пример приводил, когда многопоточка добавляет. Я потому и писал выше про одну задачу В одном потоке. К тому же я не спорю, просто попытался пояснить, что человек мог иметь ввиду про производительность.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, так как автор решил видимо этого не делать или просто еще не успел.

Comment: Присоединюсь к комментаторам - давно, когда изучал многопоточность и асинхронность, очень сильно помогла лекция https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtTZu8CXaGE&t. Конечно, в ней есть некоторые неточные моменты, но в целом она должна помочь автору разобраться в этой теме